# Design Followers and Followees Schema in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I want to design `followers` and `followee(following)` module for a social media application similar to **instagram**.

I've implemented following approach for the same

**Users Schema**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: null },
    gender: { type: String, default: null, enum: ['male', 'female', 'others', null] },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
    isBlocked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    profileImage: { type: String, default: null },
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
}));
```

**Followers Schema**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('followers', new Schema({
    followeeId: { type: ObjectId, required: true },
    followerId: { type: ObjectId, required: true }
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
}));
```

When using this approach **if one user has 1 million followers** then **1 million records will be created for that one user and if user followed back all the followers then count would be 2 million**

So on average:

```
user#1 has 1 million followers/followees = 1 million records // total records: 1 Million
user#2 has 1 million followers/followees = 1 million records // total records: 2 Million
.
.
user#1000 has 1 million followers/followees = 1 million records // total records: 1 Billion
.
.
user#1,000,000 has 1 million followers/followees = 1 million records // total records: 1 Trillion
```

There would be **more than trillions of records in a collection** if I use this approach

### So is it okay to generate records like this?

Or please suggest if there is any different approach to design this schema

Answer (score 1):

Storing follower/following data in a list is such a wrong approach. If you have 1 million followers, you will have 1 million in the list of User table, making getting 1 user from the list extremely cumbersome. Also, you can't do pagination in that case.
Also, as you mentioned-

> The size of ObjectId is 12 bytes and the limit per document is 16 MB.
> So, after calculation, we can store about 1.4 million ObjectIds
> (700,000 followers and 700,000 followees) and followers can easily
> surpass the 2 million mark.

This is another reason why you shouldn't be storing follower/followee information in lists.

**My advice-**

Make a relationship table like this:

```
Follower_UserId | Following_UserId | Timestamp
```

So if Mel follows Pushpit then the entry would be like-

```
Mel_Id | Pushpit_Id | May 31
```

More examples-

```
Ash_Id | Pushpit_Id | May 30

Mel_Id | Ash_Id | May 31
```

Table size should be the least of your concern in this approach.
Data storage is cheap. The per-row size of this relationship table would be tiny. There are so many optimization techniques to handle large tables with many small-sized rows.

Answer (score 0):

Good job finding the flaw in your own code. According to your schema, it will create too many records but there is another problem of querying the database at the time of finding followers of a user, it would be a little slow and you have to make a separate query as well!

So there must be another way. One more thing, it is always a best practice to name the model with a capital letter.

Here's what I would do with the same problem.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: null },
    gender: { type: String, default: null, enum: ['male', 'female', 'others', null] },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
    isBlocked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    profileImage: { type: String, default: null },
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    followers: [{type: ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true}],
    following: [{type: ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true}]
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
}));
```

I would add 'followers' and 'following' field which contains arrays of ObjectIds of different users. So, each time someone follows a user, you would update the record of both the users - add the followee to the following field of the follower user and vice versa.

This approach would require doing two database update queries at the time someone follows someone. But it would save tonnes of resources and the time of querying later (you don't need to do a separate query for this).

Please let me know if you find any mistakes in this approach too.

Comment: I thought of this apporach you mentioned....but size of ObjectId is 12 bytes and limit per document is 16 MB. So, after calculation we can store about 1.4 million ObjectIds (700,000 followers and 700,000 followees) and followers can be easily surpass 2 million mark.